# Filtering the dates range based on the days

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with columns as

```
    Id (1)
    Date holding values as (2013-12-12 00:00:00)
    Start time (00:00:00)
    end time (01:00:00)
    value
```

The user will give the date range and will specify day like sunday ,monday etc .

How can I use a sql query to filter the dates and find the proper days between that for the specified days as well.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to use [`BETWEEN ... AND ...`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between) and [`DAYOFWEEK()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofweek):

```
SELECT *
FROM   my_table
WHERE  Date BETWEEN ? AND ?
   AND DAYOFWEEK(Date) = ? -- 1=Sunday ... 7=Saturday
```